# et qui - how do you really understand that kind of phraseology?

Tags: sens, conjonctions, pronoms-relatifs

> Dans le programme d’aujourd’hui on continue de parler des évènements en Lybie **et qui** ont eu beaucoup d’effet sur les pays de l’Afrique du Nord, le Moyen Orient et le monde entier.

I'm not sure how to understand that. As far as I know, **qui** is a relative pronoun in French that can be translated into English as **that**, **which** or **who**. Therefore, **et qui ont eu** literally means **and which had**, but I don't think the sentence reads well that way. If we remove **et**, then the sentence makes more sense to me: **the events in Libya that had a lot of effect on...**. That **et** (**and**) makes it hard for me to process this sentence. I think I don't understand something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. This is not standard French. It's likely that the writer started to phrase the sentence in a certain way and then changed it but didn't complete that change. For example, maybe the sentence was originally “*… des évènements qui ont eu lieu en Lybie et qui ont eu …*”, then the writer decided that “*qui ont eu lieu*” was uselessly wordy and removed it.

Or maybe the writer was just careless or hurried, and has this “*qui ont eu lieu*” in mind but didn't write it. The sentence as a whole has a bit of an informal feeling, with the use of *on* (instead of a definite subject) and the lack of a comma after “*Dans le programme d'aujourd'hui*”.

A more correct way to write this sentence would be

> Dans le programme d’aujourd’hui**,** **nous continuerons** de parler des évènements en Lybie**,** qui ont eu beaucoup d’effet sur les pays de l’Afrique du Nord, le Moyen Orient et le monde entier.

“*Nous continuerons*” is correct if the author of the sentence is a participant in the program. If they aren't, then I think the sentence calls for naming the participants, or referring to them by some generic designation like “*Pierre Durand et ses invités*”.

The sentence is correct with and without a comma after *Lybie*, but leaving it out changes the meaning. With a comma, this is about “the events in Lybia” and the reader is supposed to already know which events the sentence is about; the part after the comma states an additional property of these events. Without a comma, “*qui ont eu beaucoup d'effect …*” specifies which events the sentence is about.

None of this matters very much to a native speaker. The sentence looks a bit odd, but there's no potential for misunderstanding.

Comment: This " et qui" is surely faulty. But "qui" is not perfect as it does not resolve the ambiguity about the target to which the pronoun is pointing : événements ? Lybie ? In this context "lesquels" could be much better.

Comment: @Jhor Your statement concerning the ambiguity of the pronoun is inaccurate, _évènements_ is plural whereas _Lybie_ (Libye ? whatever) is singular and the verb following the pronoun is in the plural form (_ont eu_, not _a eu_) and therefore it cannot refer to _Lybie_; in any case a country cannot meaningfully have "an/lots of effect" on other countries in French in this context.